# For an IM app, if I reloadData frequently, Is it possible the main thread be blocked? If yes, any good way to solve it?

Tags: ios

I have a IM app. It contains a UITableView. When I get a message or send a message , I push the message to my custom datasource message array, and then reloadData of the UITableView.During reload data,I calculate the expected height of the cells. I test the performance using Instruments. And in Time profiler,the most time is spent to do the reload job...And it should be done in the main thread. It seems it is unavoidable..What is a good design of a IM app? If I spend a lot of time in the main thread, the main thread will be blocked,and I receive a memory warning, am I right? Just want to know some idea about it..
PS: IM app is InstantMessaging app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to reload the whole table view every time, but you should only reload the section (or row) with the new message using `- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections` or `- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`.

To answer your question, if the main thread is blocked by a long operation it won't send you a memory warning but your UI will be blocked making your app unresponsive therefore impacting the user experience.

Comment: then use `- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`

Comment: for me , every time I add a message , and reload the tableview. Should I use  "  TableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:<#(NSArray *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#> " instead?

Comment: Yes exactly, you can do that when adding/receiving a message. Don't forget you need to add it to your datasource first. Then, if you have some kind of tick/acknowledgment system (whatsapp like) you can just reload the message row.